# jquery, hiding div tags by using id of certain patterns

Tags: jquery

I have been staring at this for one hour and not sure what is wrong with this syntax:

```
        jQuery.each(ARRAY_SUB_METRICS_HIDE, function() {
            var VALUE = this;
            \$("div[id^='reportdate-'" + VALUE + "]").hide(); 

            alert(VALUE);
        });
```

my div tags are not hiding , example VALUE = 9--0--2 while i have div tags with id="9--0--2--3"

Comment: It's worth mentioning that HTML and JavaScript don't care about IDs that start with numbers, but CSS specifically has in its spec that ID selectors cannot start with numbers. It doesn't seem this will matter, but worth mentioning it just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to move the single-quote character:

```
\$("div[id^='reportdate-" + VALUE + "']").hide();
```

Currently, your final selector looks like `$("div[id^='reportdate-'902]")` (notice the wrongly placed quote).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery.each(ARRAY_SUB_METRICS_HIDE, function() {
        var VALUE = this;
        $("div[id^='reportdate-" + VALUE + "']").hide(); 

        alert(VALUE);
    });
```